# Crop a Portion of UIImage from Larger UIImage, and include non-image parts

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimage, ios7, crop

I think I may have an odd request, however hopefully someone can help. I am using the well known `UIScrollView` + `UIImageView` to zoom into and out of an image, as well as pan. This works fine and dandy, but the current project we have needs to be able to crop the image, but also include the black bars on the sides if the image is smaller than the crop rectangle. See the images below.

We wish to capture everything inside of the blue box, including the white (which will be black, since opaque is set to `YES`).
[image]

This works great for images that are completely zoomed out (The white is just the UIImageView's extra space).
[image]

However the problem arises when we try to zoom into the image, and capture only that portion, plus the empty space.
[image]

This results in the following image
[image]

The problem we are seeing is we need to be able to create an image that is exactly what is in the Crop Rect, regardless if there is part of the image there or not. The other problem is we wish to have the ability to dynamically change the output resolution. The aspect ratio is 16:9, and for this example `kMaxWidth = 1136` and `kMaxHeight = 639`, however in the future we may want to request a larger or smaller 16:9 resolution.

Below is the function I have so far:

```
- (UIImage *)createCroppedImageFromImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGSize newRect = CGSizeMake(kMaxWidth, kMaxHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect, YES, 0.0);

    // 0 is the edge of the screen, to help with zooming
    CGFloat xDisplacement = ((abs(0 - imageView.frame.origin.x) * kMaxWidth) / (self.cropSize.width / self.scrollView.zoomScale) / self.scrollView.zoomScale);

    CGFloat yDisplacement = ((abs(self.cropImageView.frame.origin.y - imageView.frame.origin.y) * kMaxHeight) / (self.cropSize.height / self.scrollView.zoomScale) / self.scrollView.zoomScale);

    CGFloat newImageWidth = (self.image.size.width * kMaxWidth) / (self.cropSize.width / self.scrollView.zoomScale);
    CGFloat newImageHeight = (self.image.size.height * kMaxHeight) / (self.cropSize.height / self.scrollView.zoomScale);    
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(xDisplacement, 0, newImageWidth, newImageHeight)];
    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return croppedImage;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just taking a screenshot, and cropping that. It seems to work well enough.

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage {
    CGRect cropRect = self.cropOverlay.cropRect;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *fullScreenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGImageRef croppedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(fullScreenshot.CGImage, cropRect);
    UIImage *crop = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImage] resizedImage:self.outputSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
    CGImageRelease(croppedImage);
    return crop;
}
```

If using iOS 7, you would use `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`, instead of `renderInContext:`

Answer (score 0):

I think the translated rect for the image view isn't calculated properly. Since UIImageView is the subview inside the UIScrollView, you should be able to calculate the visible rect by calling `[scrollView convertRect:scrollView.bounds toView:imageView];`. That will be the visible rect of your image view. All you need to now is crop it.

```
-(UIImage*)cropImage:(UIImage*)img inRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGImageRef cropped = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(img.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cropped];

    CGImageRelease(cropped);
    return image;
}
```

**Edit:** Yeah... I forgot to mention that cropping should be done in (0,1) coordinate space. I've modified the crop function for you, so it crops the image based on all parameters you provided, UIImageView inside UIScrollView and an image.

```
-(UIImage*)cropImage:(UIImage*)image inImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView scrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView{
    // get visible rect from image scrollview
    CGRect visibleRect = [scrollView convertRect:scrollView.bounds toView:imageView];
    UIImage* rCroppedImage;

    CALayer* maskLayer= [[CALayer alloc] init];

    maskLayer.contents= (id)image.CGImage;
    maskLayer.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, visibleRect.size.width, visibleRect.size.height);

    CGRect rect= CGRectMake(visibleRect.origin.x / image.size.width,
                            visibleRect.origin.y / image.size.height,
                            visibleRect.size.width / image.size.width,
                            visibleRect.size.height / image.size.height);
    maskLayer.contentsRect= rect;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(visibleRect.size);

    CGContextRef context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [maskLayer renderInContext:context];

    rCroppedImage= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return rCroppedImage;
}
```

Comment: I used your function like
`[self cropImage:self.image inRect:[self.scrollView convertRect:self.scrollView.bounds toView:imageView]]` however it did not work at all.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the value of rect you are getting?

Comment: A few things. 
1. This needs to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, with opaque set to YES to give us the black bars on the left and right (this is mandatory).
2. Using this with opaque = YES makes the phone crash, not just the app.
3. There is no use of `kMaxWidth` and `kMaxHeight` to specify what the output image size is going to be.

Comment: Using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(visibleRect.size, YES, scrollView.zoomScale);` helps make the `UIImage` not cause the crash, however the image is not what I am looking for. It is the size of the screen, where I only am looking for the Crop Rect, and it is also the entire image.